# Android to Android Files Sync over LAN

Tags: sync, data-transfer, lan

I have an Android TV Box which is always in WiFi Hotspot Mode. I want to sync some files from my android phone to the TV Box when I connect to the Android Box AP WiFi on my phone.

I could find some apps which sync data between Android and PC. But I want Android-Android sync. Is there such an app available on Play Store?

The box runs Android version 4.0.4 and phone can have any Android version.